# Get sound output with WaveIn?

Tags: c++, audio

I wrote a program in C++ that gets microphone input with WaveIn and analyzes it. I'd love to have the option of changing the input source from microphone input to the sound output from Windows, but I really don't know how to do that, and many of the search results were in C#, which isn't helpful to me. The person paying for the application really wants it to be in C++.

Could anyone help me out with a way to capture sound output with WaveIn, or perhaps another API? The program is intended to be run on Windows 7 only, and I'm currently using Visual C++ 2010 to program, if that helps you at all.

Comment: You need to select a different recording device. Many Win7 machines have "Stereo Mix" disabled by default - Go to recording devices and right-click the white space under the Microphone entry. You should get an option to Show Disabled. Then, enable Stereo mix and you should be able to select it and use it exactly the same way as the Mic

Comment: Vista+ support "loopback recording" via WASAPI  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316551(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Both of these comments were very helpful. I think I'm going to take Basic's advice and then just work in a toggle to select the different devices. Thanks guys! As a sidenote, this is my first question and I don't know how to close it or acknowledge a good answer, if that's possible.

Comment: Ask @Basic (@ symbol to get his attention) to post his comment as an answer, then accept it.

Comment: @AlexK. Works like a charm :) Thanks. Posted as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, from comments on OP...

You need to select a different recording device. Many Win7 machines have "Stereo Mix" disabled by default

Go to recording devices and right-click the white space under the Microphone entry. You should get an option to Show Disabled. Then, enable Stereo mix and you should be able to select it and use it exactly the same way as you would the microphone

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, this will require you to Hook waveOut calls and capture the data, and then use it as input to microphone. Which means hook waveIn as well.

Comment: This is a good option. I'll keep this in mind if Basic's option doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

When you open WaveIn device, instead of using `WAVE_MAPPER` as device ID, set the device explicitly

The device identifier specified by uDeviceID varies from zero to one less than the number of devices present - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can browse through all devices this way:

```
  WAVEINCAPS wc; 

  /* Get the number of Digital Audio Out devices in this computer */ 
  int n_devices = waveInGetNumDevs(); 

  for (int i = 0; i < n_devices; i++) 
  { 
    if (!waveInGetDevCaps(i, &wc, sizeof (WAVEINCAPS))) 
      printf("device id #%d: %s\n", i, wc.szPname); 
  }
```

Comment: This code is extremely helpful, but for some reason I only get one result which is always the selected default recording device. waveOutGetNumDevs() is always returning 1. Any thoughts?

Comment: Wow, duh. I figured it out. It should be waveInGetNumDevs(). Still a great help! Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry , my bad, I fixed it though.